# How do Arrays work in the "for" loop (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, loops

i am relatively new in c programming, and programming in general.

1) I am trying to create an array named "input" that will be used for the user input (and the array will only use two integer elements).

2) I want to use the for loop so it loop through my code 2 times, so i can duplicate the printf statement "Enter an integer," without me typing the printf statement multiple times. And then my scanf placeholder will be based my array "input."

3) Then i want to add those two numbers together for the sum.

**The problem:** When the user enters a number, for example, 1 and then 1 again, the index at input[0] is 1 but then the index at 1 for input[1] is 2...

I will use addition to try and explain.
When i try to output the numbers in addition (integer[0] is 1, integer[1] is 2 and my variable which adds them together is "total")i get this: **1+2=2.**

So why is input[0] correct, but input[1] seems to be adding the two user inputs together and storing it in there?

Here is my code

```
int main()
{
    int input[1];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer: ");

        scanf("%d", &input[i]);

    }
    int total = input[0]+input[1];
    printf("%d + %d = %d ", input[0], input[1], total);


}
```

Thanks in advance, and i hope you understand me. Sorry i'm a noob, learning the basics so i can become advanced.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!!! I appreciate your help and explanation haha. I feel pretty stupid.

Comment: Please accept the answer (the one you found helpful) :). Every one is a beginner for some point of time , so chill :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
int input[2];
```

since you want an array of two integers. Otherwise , it will just allocate one integer array for you, and accessing input[1] in that case will not work properly.

Also try this to extend that to adding n integers.

```
int main()
{
int input[1];
int total = 0;
int n; //To count number of elements to add:
  printf("Please enter the number of elements to add: ");

    scanf("%d", &n);

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("Please enter integer %d: ",(i+1));

    scanf("%d", &input[i]);

}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    total = total +input[i];

}

printf("The sum is = ", total);


}
```

So in your array, as indicated in the loops I have used, you will be accessing a **single** element of *input* array in each iteration by making use of its *index* which you also increment in each iteration.

In your case, there are only *two* elements, so it requires two iterations only.

Answer (score 3):

this line

> int input[1];

will create array of size one only. And i can see you are trying to access second element of array also.

so just replace your this line with

> int input[2];

this will solve your problem.
or put this whole thing

> 

```
int main()
{
    int input[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer: ");

        scanf("%d", &input[i]);

    }
    int total = input[0]+input[1];
    printf("%d + %d = %d ", input[0], input[1], total);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
int main()
{
    int input[2];  //initializes array of size 2,which can contain maximun 3-->(0,1,2)
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer: ");

        scanf("%d", &input[i]);

    }
    int total = input[0]+input[1];
    printf("%d + %d = %d ", input[0], input[1], total);


}
```

**OR** use `i<=2`.

```
int main()
{
    int input[1];  //initializes array of size 1 which can contain -->(0,1),or use i<=2
    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer: ");

        scanf("%d", &input[i]);

    }
    int total = input[0]+input[1];
    printf("%d + %d = %d ", input[0], input[1], total);


}
```